# How to combine Create and Update form & process in MEVN stack?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, vue.js, mongoose

Has anybody combined their edit and create forms in a MEVN stack? For example Moongoose's save method can create or update but I'm not sure how you handle passing in the ID if it does exist vs does not exist. Here is what I currently have for my create process & update process. It would be nice to combine two different componenets into one that did both jobs.

CreateStudent.vue

```
handleSubmitForm() {
  console.log("handleSubmitForm")
  this.isSubmitted = true;
  let apiURL = "http://localhost:4000/api/create-student";

  axios
    .post(apiURL, this.student)
    .then(() => {
      this.$router.push("/list");
      this.student = {
        firstName: "",
        lastName: "",
        email: "",
        phone: "",
        password: "",
        confirmPassword: "",
      };
      //alert("SUCCESS! " + JSON.stringify(this.userForm));
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    })
    .finally((next) => {
       // console.log('is Submiited);
    })
},

studentRoute.route("/create-student").post((req, res, next) => {
    StudentModel.create(req.body, (error, data) => {
        if (error) {
            return next(error);
        } else {
            res.json(data);
        }
    })
})
```

EditStudent.vue

```
handleUpdateForm() {
  let apiURL = `http://localhost:4000/api/update-student/${this.$route.params.id}`;

  axios.post(apiURL, this.student).then((res) => {
      console.log(res)
      this.$router.push('/list')
  }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error)
  });
}

studentRoute.route('/update-student/:id').post((req, res, next) => {
    StudentModel.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {
      $set: req.body
    }, (error, data) => {
      if (error) {
        return next(error);
      } else {
        res.json(data)
        console.log('Student successfully updated!')
      }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs you can simple send in an options to findByIdAndUpdate, one of them is upsert

> [options.upsert=false] if true, and no documents found, insert a new
> document

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#Model.findByIdAndUpdate()

So something like

```
StudentModel.findOneAndUpdate(
  { _id: req.params.id },
  { $set: req.body },
  { upsert: true } // Make this update into an upsert
);
```

should work both as update or insert

Answer (score 1):

It is better to handle updates and creates separately. [@Bergur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5189472/bergur) is correct in that `findOneAndUpdate` and `findByIdAndUpdate` have an `upsert` option that will allow you to update or insert if no document matches. However, in my experience this typically works initially and then the problems start.

The key sticking point is validation. With `findOneAndUpdate` and `findByIdAndUpdate` you can also pass the `runValidators: true` option to tell mongoose to run the validators but this only works on fields included in the update document and [only for some operations](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html). So if you have a constraint on a field and you don't pass that field in the update document then mongoose won't do any validation. That can have some negative consequences.

To illustrate a simple schema would look like:

```js
const studentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   firstName: {
      type: String,
      required: true
   },
   lastName: {
      type: String,
      required: true
   },
   veryImportantProperty: {
      type: String,
      required: true
   },
});
```

Now if you do a `findOneAndUpdate` or `findByIdAndUpdate` like so:

```js
req.body = {
   firstName: 'Bruce'
   lastName: 'Wayne'
   //< Whoops, veryImportantProperty wasn't included in the post request
}
const student = await Student.findByIdAndUpdate(
   req.params.id,
   req.body,
   {
      upsert: true, 
      runValidators: true, 
      new: true
   }
);
```

Then no validation is done on `veryImportantProperty` even with the `runValidators` option because it wasn't included in `req.body` so mongoose will create the document without it.

Even if you use the `$set` operator like so:

```js
const student = await Student.findByIdAndUpdate(
   req.params.id,
   { $set: req.body },
   {
      upsert: true, 
      runValidators: true, 
      new: true
   }
);
```

It will still save the new document without `veryImportantProperty`. With `Model.create()` you give yourself better data integrity, it's easier to debug and you can send better error responses back to the user if a create operation fails.

This is a simple example but with more complex validations things can get messy very quickly and it will be difficult to debug, especially if you revisit your codebase after some time away.